# How do I compare string data between cells in a google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, string-comparison

If I copy/paste the information into both cells my script runs correctly and matches the strings in the cells to the correct row for the user so I can lookup their email. If I let my google form fill the first cell however the data in the two cells no longer matches. I'm probably overlooking something obvious about comparing the strings but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Here is the code I have so far.

```
var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
var cell  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rows, 2);  
var value = cell.getValue().toString();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]);
var sheet;
var teacher;
var cc = "no match";
for(var h=1; h <= ss.getLastRow(); h++)
    {
      sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(h, 2);
       teacher = sheet.getValue().toString();
       if (value == teacher)
                 cc = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(h, 1).getValue().toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use watchdog (clicking on line number) or some message box to see what happens
i.e.   Browser.msgBox(teacher); bebore testing the value of value ^^

and may be don t use the "value" as a variable name, it could generate problem to execute the script.